# React: What should I use for interaction with API?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm writing frontend application on React + Redux. And I faced with the issue: how should I interact with my backend API. After some researchring I have found several possibilities:

- custom middleware (pro: do what you only need, cons: can have some side-effects in the future)
- redux-api-middleware (pro: library which implements RSAA & FSA standards, cons: isn't currently maintained)
- redux-thunk (pro: relatively simple, cons: repetitive code, harder testing)
- other libraries

As I understand this decision is crucial for development since it will be hard to change middleware (library) in the future.

What is the common way to handle it nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

[redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) is very powerful, flexible and popular middleware for Redux.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236906/react-what-should-i-use-for-interaction-with-api/58237457#comment102856517_58237457

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on a large scale application, we are using redux-saga middleware.. i think this is easy to manage, smooth and more efficient than other libraries..
Further details: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: good to know. But I think that this tool is applicable mostly for complex action flow rather than simple API calls (in my case). So I'm still torn between redux-api-middleware and custom middleware